# R leaflet how to click on map and add a circle

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

Hi guys I have been trying this for weeks but I couldn't manage to get it done. Online resources for R leaflet are not enough too. Really need to get this done.

Please help, thank you so much.

ui.R -->

```
library(shiny)
library(ggmap)
library(leaflet)

shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  leafletOutput("map"),
  br(),
  verbatimTextOutput("out")
)
)
```

server.R -->

```
library(shiny)
library(ggmap)
library(leaflet)


shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {


output$map <- renderLeaflet({

 p <- input$map_click

 if(is.null(p)){
   leaflet() %>% setView(lng = -43.1729, lat = -22.9068, zoom = 11) %>%
     addTiles(options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) 
 }

 else{
   address <- revgeocode(c(p$lng,p$lat))

   leaflet() %>% setView(lng = p$lng, lat = p$lat, zoom = 16) %>%
   addTiles(options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%
   addCircles(p$lng, p$lat, weight = 1, radius = 100, color =  "black",
                    fillColor = "orange", popup = address, fillOpacity=0.5, opacity=1)
 }


})

output$out <- renderPrint({
validate(need(input$map_click, FALSE))
click <- input$map_click
clat <- click$lat
clng <- click$lng
address <- revgeocode(c(clng,clat))
print(clat)
print(clng)
print(address)

})

})
```

Comment: Please create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Show what code you've tried and describe how it's not working.

Comment: Hi MrFlick, I have put up the code. It is working but I wonder is there any better way to improve this

Comment: Voted to reopen now that you've shown what you've attempted, but as MrFlick suggested, also describe what you're trying to do and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL; DR**

1. Create the initial map so it is ***not*** dependent on user input.
2. Use an observer that responds to user clicks to update the map.
3. Use `leafletProxy` to update the map without rendering everything all over again.

I would do this by making your original map and using the `leafletProxy` function to update the map when the user clicks on locations.  There is a tutorial on the Rstudio site somewhere where they show how to do this.  It will hopefully save some computation, since the map won't be re-rendered every time a circle is added.

I also add a couple additional things I would consider: putting the circle data in a reactive dataset, and maintaining the circles in a group, thus allowing you to easily hide/show them with an additional observer/button.

Here, is a working example.  For the record, I'm using the leaflet version from github (and recommend this since this package is under active development).  You can get it with `devtools::install_github('rstudio/leaflet')`.  There are at least a couple new features that I don't think are on CRAN yet -- like easily being able to create custom markers.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggmap)
library(leaflet)

ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  leafletOutput("map")
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  ## One alternative: store circles data?
  ## I dont actually implement this, but you would do this in the observer as well
  dat <- reactiveValues(circs = data.frame(lng=numeric(), lat=numeric()))

  ## Make your initial map
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      setView(lng = -43.1729, lat = -22.9068, zoom = 11) %>%
        addTiles(options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) 
  })

  ## Observe mouse clicks and add circles
  observeEvent(input$map_click, {
    ## Get the click info like had been doing
    click <- input$map_click
    clat <- click$lat
    clng <- click$lng
    address <- revgeocode(c(clng,clat))

    ## Add the circle to the map proxy
    ## so you dont need to re-render the whole thing
    ## I also give the circles a group, "circles", so you can
    ## then do something like hide all the circles with hideGroup('circles')
    leafletProxy('map') %>% # use the proxy to save computation
      addCircles(lng=clng, lat=clat, group='circles',
                 weight=1, radius=100, color='black', fillColor='orange',
                 popup=address, fillOpacity=0.5, opacity=1)
  })

})

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

The result should look something like this (I've zoomed in, added some circles and activated a popup).

[image]

Comment: Hi man, your example works like a charm. This is exactly what I am trying to do. God bless you and all the best in your future. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since shiny 1.6.0, `observeEvent(event,expression)` has been deprecated in favour of `observe(expression) %>% bindEvent(event)`. So [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34352005/7372346) by @Rorschach would become:

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggmap)
library(leaflet)

ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  leafletOutput("map")
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  ## One alternative: store circles data?
  ## I dont actually implement this, but you would do this in the observer as well
  dat <- reactiveValues(circs = data.frame(lng=numeric(), lat=numeric()))

  ## Make your initial map
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      setView(lng = -43.1729, lat = -22.9068, zoom = 11) %>%
        addTiles(options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) 
  })

  ## Observe mouse clicks and add circles
  observe({
    ## Get the click info like had been doing
    click <- input$map_click
    clat <- click$lat
    clng <- click$lng
    address <- revgeocode(c(clng,clat))

    ## Add the circle to the map proxy
    ## so you dont need to re-render the whole thing
    ## I also give the circles a group, "circles", so you can
    ## then do something like hide all the circles with hideGroup('circles')
    leafletProxy('map') %>% # use the proxy to save computation
      addCircles(lng=clng, lat=clat, group='circles',
                 weight=1, radius=100, color='black', fillColor='orange',
                 popup=address, fillOpacity=0.5, opacity=1)
  }) %>%
  bindEvent(input$map_click)

})

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```