# Display coordinates in a table when markers are dragged in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-leaflet

In my simple shiny app, I'm able to drag the markers on the map and see their new coordinates in `observe` function :

```
coords_data <- data.frame(id = 1:3, lng = c(2, 30, 50), lat = c(48, 40, 60)) 

library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)

ui = fluidPage(
    leafletOutput('map'),
    textOutput('dragEndLocation')
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  
    output$map <-renderLeaflet({ 
      leaflet()%>%
        addTiles()%>%
        addMarkers(data = coords_data, 
                   options = markerOptions(draggable = TRUE))
      
    })
    
    
      observe({
        print(input$map_marker_dragend)
      })
    

                   
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

however, I would like to print the final coordinates in a table which I don't know how !
I tried [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549325/how-to-update-coordinates-after-dragging-a-marker-in-leaflet-shiny) but was not successful.

Furthermore I want to replace the markers by circles :

```
coords_data <- data.frame(id = 1:3, lng = c(2, 30, 50), lat = c(48, 40, 60)) 

library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)

ui = fluidPage(
    leafletOutput('map'),
    textOutput('dragEndLocation')
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  
    output$map <-renderLeaflet({ 
      leaflet()%>%
        addTiles()%>%
        addCircles(data = coords_data, 
                   options = markerOptions(draggable = TRUE),
                   radius = 100,color="red")%>%
        addDrawToolbar(circleOptions=NA, markerOptions=NA,
                       polygonOptions=NA, rectangleOptions=NA,
                       polylineOptions=NA)
      
    })
    
    
      observe({
        print(input$map_marker_dragend)
      })
    

                   
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In this case I still can move the circles around but I don't know how to get their new coordinates.
Any help or suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)

coords_data <- data.frame(id = 1:3, lng = c(2, 30, 50), lat = c(48, 40, 60))

ui = fluidPage(
  leafletOutput('map'),
  tableOutput('coordsTable')
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  
  coords_rv <- reactiveValues(data = coords_data)
  
  output$map <-renderLeaflet({ 
    leaflet()%>%
      addTiles()%>%
      addMarkers(data = coords_data,
                       lng = ~lng, lat = ~lat,
                       layerId = ~id, 
                       options = markerOptions(draggable = TRUE))
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$map_marker_dragend, {
    
    markerId <- input$map_marker_dragend$id
    lat <- input$map_marker_dragend$lat
    lng <- input$map_marker_dragend$lng
    
    
    coords_rv$data[coords_rv$data$id == markerId, c("lat", "lng")] <- c(lat, lng)
    
    
    leafletProxy('map') %>% clearMarkers() %>% clearGroup("rad")%>%
      addMarkers(data = coords_rv$data,
                       lng = ~lng, lat = ~lat,
                       layerId = ~id,
                       options = markerOptions(draggable = TRUE))%>%
      addCircles(data = coords_rv$data,
                 lng = ~lng, lat = ~lat,
                 layerId = ~id,radius = 10000,color="red",group = "rad")
  })
  
  
  output$coordsTable <- renderTable({
    coords_rv$data
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```